# How often does a cookie change?

Tags: internet, cookies

Is there a policy per browser or is it an automatically the client receives notice from server?

Comment: How could the browser decide to change the cookie?

Answer (score 3):

A cookie changes as often as the server changes it and the browser accepts it. While the browser sends the cookies for each request, the server may send or withhold setting a cookie with the response as it desires.